# Como verificar se uma string está dentro de um conjunto de strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

No código abaixo eu tenho o conjunto de strings `('M', 'F')` e logo depois eu peço para o usuário digitar o seu sexo para que o valor seja registrado.

```
valores = ('M','F')
print(valores)

sexo = str(input('Digite o seu sexo [M/F]: ')).upper()[0].strip()
print(sexo)

if sexo == valores:
    print('Valor registrado com sucesso.')
else:
    print('Dados incorretos. Digite novamente.')
```

Eu quero verificar se a resposta do usuário está dentro dos valores que eu defini, porém não consigo fazê-lo pois mesmo que digite o valor correto, ele informa que está errado. Veja abaixo:

```
('M','F')
Digite o seu sexo [M/F]: m
M
Dados incorretos. Digite novamente.
```

Por qual motivo isso está acontecendo ? Como posso verificar se o valor é válido ou não ?

Comment: Não consigo detetar o meu erro

Comment: Só um detalhe: em Python 3, `input` já retorna uma string, não precisa fazer `str(input(...))`. E se vc já pega o primeiro caractere dela (com `[0]`), também não precisa chamar `strip` depois (se o primeiro caractere for um espaço, tanto faz removê-lo ou não, já que vc vai verificar se é M ou F e não fará diferença)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu não entendi muito bem a parte de "utilizar string como valor", mas sim é possível verificar se uma string está dentro de uma lista, tupla e outros iteráveis.

No seu código de exemplo, a comparação retornava `False` porque uma string é **diferente** de uma tupla contendo strings, assim como `"1"` é diferente de `1`. Para verificar se uma string está dentro de um iterável (no seu caso uma tupla de strings), você deve substituir o operador `==` pelo `in`. Veja como ficaria:

```
valores = ('M', 'F')
print(valores)

sexo = input('Digite o seu sexo [M/F]: ').upper()[0].strip()
print(sexo)

if sexo in valores:
    print('Valor registado com sucesso.')
else:
    print('Dados incorretos. Digite novamente.')
```

O operador `in` diferentemente do `==`, verifica se um objeto (pode ser um objeto de qualquer tipo) está dentro de um iterável, ou melhor dizendo, ele verifica se o objeto alvo contém o objeto que você está especificando.

Você pode fazer essa verificação não só com strings, mas também com objetos de outros tipos. Veja os exemplos abaixo:

```
"Masculino"  in  ["Masculino", "Feminino"]          # True
17           in  [19, 23, 3, 1023, 17, 65]          # True
3            in  ["3", 2, True, "bola"]             # False ("3" é diferente de 3)
True         in  [False, True, False, False]        # True
```

Lembra que eu falei que o `in` verifica se um objeto contém um elemento ? Então... essa verificação ocorre através do método `__contains__` que recebe um valor e verifica se há ou não o objeto passado. Exemplo:

```
class MinhaClasse():
    def __contains__(self, value):

        if value == 7:
            return True
        else:
            return False

objeto = MinhaClasse()

3 in objeto  # False
7 in objeto  # True
```

Note que o objeto a ser verificado fica sempre antes do operador. Logo se eu invertesse o código para `objeto in 7`, eu estaria verificando se o objeto está no número `7` e além de não funcionar, ainda iria gerar um erro, porque `int` não possui o método `__contains__`.

Comment: Já ia responder, mas vi sua resposta! creio que era isto que o Ruben queria! Parabens

Comment: muito obrigado!!! Era isso mesmo que pretendia.

Comment: Então não necessito de colocar ' ' quando atribuo um valor?

Comment: a = (texto1, texto2), se eu quiser veriicar se numa variavel existe a string texto, utilizo a funçao IN, se for numero utilizo ==

Comment: É necessário sim colocar as aspas, porque uma tupla é um conjunto de elementos (no seu caso um conjunto de strings). E como você deve saber, para criar uma string, é necessário utilizar as aspas.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Desculpe a minha ignorancia, mas estou a comecar a dar os primeiros passos em programacao e estou a tentar aprender por youtube e sites

Comment: Não se preocupe, todos nós começamos do zero. A última parte da resposta é um pouco mais "avançada" então ignore por enquanto ela até começar a estudar Programação Orientada a Objetos.

Comment: ;) obrigado, vai ser útil de certeza. Por enquanto estou nas condicoes if, loop e while. Mas surgiu essa duvida durante um exercicio. Nunca assumia o masculino nem o feminino e entao o loop nao parava como era pretendido. Tive 3h para tentar resolver este problema que voce resolveu num segundo